# Do all pods work with the Multiplatform apps in the new Xcode beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods, mac-catalyst

can somebody help me with my problem?

I want to make an iOS/macOS app with the new Xcode 12 beta 2, and I use the pod SwiftyJSON in that project. It is a Multiplatform project, and for the iOS part everything works perfectly fine. But when I set the build target to macOS, Xcode shows me the error message "**No such module 'SwiftyJSON'**".

I use two other pods in that project (SwiftyXMLParser and Alamofire) and they work just fine (no error message, maybe that's because the compiler cancels the build but I don't think so, its the second pod that gets imported in the file).

Is that a problem with Cocoapods, that it doesn't support Multiplatform apps yet? Doesn't seem like it, there is a separate import section for macOS and iOS, but I'm no expert. Or do I have to do some special setup in Xcode to get these pods to work for macOS (maybe a problem with the beta?)? Or is the SwiftyJSON pod not compatible with macOS?

Or am I just dumb? (probably true)

Thanks for every answer you can give me

Comment: Hello Jonas, where you able to find a solution for this? We have stable builds for xCode now, but I still cant run my application, because of the MANY pod issues.

Comment: I haven’t tried for a few weeks now, but I will as soon as I can.